# Raise an alert/notice in rails controller WITHOUT redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to flash a notice/error if the email is/isn't saved, *without using a redirect*.  I am using Rails 4 for the project, and here is my code:

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FarFlung Jobs</title>
  <!-- /.You can include style.css into stylesheet_link_tag too. If you do so, dont forget to add style.css in asset.rb -->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', 'jobs', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'config', 'sharebutton', 'jobsalert', 'modernizr'%>
  <%= render 'payola/transactions/stripe_header' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%=  render 'shared/navbar' %>

    <div>
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: 'alert alert-info' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

<%= yield %>
    <%=  render 'shared/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<section class="cd-form-wrapper cd-container">
    <div class="column panel panel-default">
      <div class="cd-filter"><h4>SUBSCRIBE FOR JOBS ALERT</h4></div>
      <%= simple_form_for User.new do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :email, label: false, :placeholder => 'Enter your email address...', :input_html => { :class => 'newsletter-form-field-styling' } %>
          <%= f.button :submit, 'SUBMIT', :class => 'btn-block newsletter-form-styling btn-primary submit' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</section>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(secure_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
      flash.now[:notice] = "#{@user.email} is signed up for Jobs Alert."
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Error Subscribing!'
    end
  end

private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

How do I get the Rails flash message working to appear on my subscription form without redirecting the page?

Comment: no, you cant do it. u ll have template missing error. U can use `render`, its not refreshing a page. but yr new added data will not appear then, for that u have to use redirect or ajax.

Comment: @7urkm3n, my Ajax knowledge is a little rusty. What if I define Success and Error Message as "partials", and I render that partial inside my View/SignUp Form, could that solve my problem such that I have Error&Success Message right on my Form without redirecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit your form passing `remote: true`. It'll (as you can expect) remotely submit your form, so you can return an json an render the expected flash. Ex:

**Your form:**

```
simple_form_for User.new, remote: true, class: 'your-form' do 
  <your code>
```

**Your controller**

```
def create
@user = User.new(secure_params)
if @user.save
  render json: { status: 'success', message: "#{@user.email} is signed up for Jobs Alert." }
else
  render json: { status: 'failure', message: 'Error Subscribing!' }
end
```

end

**Your JS** (perhaps *new.js* - and be sure to include it in your view)

```
// you can specify your bind container, here I just used the document
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.your-form', function(e, data) {
  if(data.status == 'success'){
    showSuccessFlash(data);
  }else{
    showErrorFlash(data);
  }
});
```

Explaining:

Using the `remote: true`, your page will wait for an ajax answer, which you can get listening to `ajax:success` (or other bindings).

Then, it will receive the `json` and will store in the `data` variable. So you will get the `data.status` and the `data.message`, which you can show to your user as a feedback.

More infor about the `remote: true` http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

More info about the JS callbacks https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Yes I got JSON response back but as a redirect to my `localhost:3000/users`. I don't want redirect. I have the subscription form inside my View `index.html.erb`. 
Maybe I am doing something wrong here: the line that has `$(document).on('ajax:success', '.your-form', function(e, data) {`, what do I add to where I have `.your-form`?

Comment: if you add the `render json` in your `create` action you will not be redirected,  since you need a `redirect_to path` to be redirected. `.your-form` is a class that you add to your form, so you can "track" it. `simple_form_for User.new, remote: true, class: 'your-form' do |f|`

Comment: Am sorry, I did `render json` in my `create` action as you adviced, yet I was redirected to `localhost:3000/users`. The only thing I probably did wrong is this new update `simple_form_for User.new, remote: true, class: 'your-form' do |f|` in my **new.html.erb** because I didn't add that `class`. I will effect it. Would be nice if you could update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice solution.  I like the simple elegance of it, and the fact that it doesn't introduce new components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem like [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) that will monitor variables and handle all of the Ajax for you automatically.

It's very easy to setup, and you can have it perform the update at whatever time interval you choose.  If you're simply transporting a variable, this will save you some Ajax coding.  And it will update your page without any kind of redirect, so it does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

However, one other tweak I figured out to solve this problem is **with/without redirect** is using `application helper` to make your Flash Global and used on any View of your choice.

Move your Flash Message to Partials e.g.

**shared/_flash_messages.html.erb**

```
    <div class="text-center">
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
          <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: 'alert alert-info' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Define custom helper method for your flash messages using the exact same old rails method use to have. Such that the method renders our partials and the object will be parsed along to your partials.

**helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def flash_messages_for(object)
      render(:partial => 'shared/flash_messages', :locals => {:object => object})
   end
end
```

Inside my View, you can call it with erb tags and call the form object on it such as `<%= flash_messages_for(User.new) %>` or `<%= flash_messages_for(@user) %>`. See code below:

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<section class="cd-form-wrapper cd-container">
<div class="column panel panel-default">
  <%= flash_messages_for(User.new) %>
  <div class="cd-filter"><h4>SUBSCRIBE FOR JOBS ALERT</h4></div>
  <%= simple_form_for(User.new) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :email, label: false, :placeholder => 'Enter your email address...', :input_html => { :class => 'newsletter-form-field-styling' } %>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'SUBMIT', :class => 'btn-block newsletter-form-styling btn-primary submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

With this, my error messages are flashed on any view or form I call `<%= flash_messages_for(User.new) %>` on.

You can refer to Kevin Skoglund `formerrors` Ruby on Rails Tutorials on Lynda.com [Click to watch](https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Form-errors/139989/159140-4.html)