# using Ajax/jQuery for update action without page reload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a profile page that a current_user can view, on which it will list Events they have RSVP'd for and below each event there will be a form to update RSVP status to something different if they wish. It's radio buttons for three possible RSVP status they can select from ("attending", "interested", "not_interested"). I want to make it so that the page does not reload upon the radio button click which updates the RSVP status. Here is what the form looks like right now.

```
  <% current_user.past_events.each do |event| %>
  <% rsvp_status = current_user.rsvp_for_event(event).status %>
    <% unless rsvp_status == "not_interested" %>
  <li><%= link_to event.title, event_path(event) %>
    <%= form_for ([current_user, current_user.rsvp_for_event(event)]), remote: true, html: { class: "update" } do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
      <%= f.radio_button :status, "attending", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
                <%= f.radio_button :status, "interested", :onclick => "this.form.submit();"%>
      <%= f.radio_button :status, "not_interested", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
    <% end %>
```

User model:

```
def rsvp_for_event(event)
  Rsvp.where(:event_id => event.id).first
end
```

**UPDATE**

1) the error I'm getting is `ActionController::UnknownFormat in RsvpsController#update`

2) HTML for the the form looks like this `<form class="update" id="edit_rsvp_11" action="/users/1/rsvps/11" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">` and for each button like this `<input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="attending" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_attending">`. What do I reference in the `).on('click` part - `update` class of the form, `radio` type of the button, etc? Is there a rule of thumb here?

3) The URL contains two arbitrary params, the `user_id` and the `rsvp_id`. How do I properly work them in the data part for the AJAX request and the Rails controller?

RsvpsController

```
  def update

    #is this part sufficient?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

views/rsvps/update.js.erb, is there supposed to be another file in assets/javascripts?

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    //does the radio button reference go here?
    $('.radio').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "users/" + user_id + "/rsvps/" + rsvp_id,
            data: {
                user_id: "<%= current_user.id %>"
                //in my view template, I added "<% rsvp_id = current_user.rspv_for_event(event)" 
                rsvp_id: "<%= rsvp_id %>"
            }
        }).done(function(response){ console.log('hello?', response)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: not in your js...that ruby goes in your html `<div class="some-class" data-user-id="<%= current_user.id %>">` then in your js...you get that id by saying `var user_id = $('.some-class').data('user-id')` Put this right after the prevent default and do the same thing to get the `rsvp_id` ... whatever that is...get it off the page. Pass both of those to a controller action. The url for the controller action should be a new url that you add to routes and define in your controller. Not the show route.

Comment: updated my answer to show you in part.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you need the `update.js.erb` if you want it to respond in javascript without reloading the page.
2. In order to specify that your form submits on click of a radio button, you've already answered your own question. You need to add a click listener onto the radio buttons themselves.

**Click listener**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.radio-button-yes').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // Not necessary but here for precaution

    $.ajax... 
    // This is where you make your post to update action in controller
    // Make sure to specify type to be 'js'
  })

  // Repeat for the '.radio-button-no' class
</script>
```

**update.js.erb**

Anything can happen in javascript here so I'll just give an example.

```
$(body).css({"backgroundColor":"pink"});
```

Comment: Is there any rule of thumb? Should I use something from the form part that the buttons are wrapped in, I have `<form class="update" id="edit_rsvp_11" action="/users/1/rsvps/11" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">`, so something like `$('.edit_rsvp)...`.

Comment: Or go straight for the button element, so if I have `<input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="attending" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_attending">`, do something like `$('.radio).on('click' etc`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery? Bind a click event to whatever element you'd like to trigger an update. For example:

in your routes:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post "rsvp_to_event"
  end
end
```

in your controller:

```
def rsvp_to_event
  user_id = params[:user_id]
  rsvp_id = params[:rsvp_id]

  # do what you need to do

  # then render json and send back whatever you need

  render json: {data: "Success"}
end
```

in your view:

```
<button class="some-class" data-user-id="<%= current_user.id %>">Example</button>

<script>
   $(document).on('ready', function(){
     $('.some-class').on('click', function(e){
     // this keeps page from reloading
     e.preventDefault()

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/controller_action_you_want_to_post_to',
       data: { user_id: $('.some-class').data('user-id') }
     }).done(function(response){ console.log('response', response })
     // you can update the page in the done callback
     // update your data in the controller action you're posting to
    }
   })
</script>
```

Comment: my urls for rsvp_update currently look like this `/users/1/rsvps/11`, depend on two separate id's (user_id and rsvp_id) that constantly change. What's a good way to handle that?

Comment: Pass them both as params to the data object inside that $.Ajax request. Then in the controller action get them both 'params[:user_id]' and handle there.

Comment: I've updated the OP with what I've come up with, didn't find any Rails + Ajax examples of this online.

Comment: Data attributes shouldn't be equals signs. 'User_id:'

Comment: Also...are those values defined? You need to grab them w/ JS

Comment: To get those values, add data-user-id="<%= current_user.id %>" to an element...then get it by saying `$('.class-on-element').data('user-id')`

Comment: updated the js part, is that what you meant? I'm getting a template missing error on the controller update action, I tried `format.js { render update.js.erb }`, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: `rsvp_for_event` is currently in the User *model*, not controller. Its purpose is to retrieve and filter user's RSVP's based on the rsvp status. for example, I have a line `<% rsvp_status = current_user.rsvp_for_event(event).status %>` in my view. Should I really move it into the controller?

Comment: `rsvp_for_event` was just an example name...ignore the name and don't use for the controller action if you already have a method with that name. I was just suggesting that instead of using a form you just create a custom controller action and update your rsvp there.

Comment: is this code on github? I could take a look and maybe more easily explain / show you.

Comment: it's here https://github.com/syivanes/event_app . files in question are `sessions/show.html.erb`, `rsvps/update.js.erb`, `models/user.rb`, `controllers/rsvps_controller.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ajax:success` bind. You just need the [`jquery-ujs`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) gem.

I've explained how it works in this post
[Raise an alert/notice in rails controller WITHOUT redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533969/raise-an-alert-notice-in-rails-controller-without-redirect/37536247#37536247)

So using  `remote: true`, rails will submit your form using ajax and then you can catch the return with those `ajax:something` binds and manipulate the result as you want :)