# making rails respond_to format js for an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to make an Ajax request that makes an update upon a radio button click without reloading an entire page.

Update action definition in my controller. There really not that much info on this part in the Rails docs.

```
 def update
    if @rsvp.update(rsvp_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

update.js.erb, not sure if this code even works, but I can't test it since Rails is not even finding it:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.rsvp').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        var user_id = $(.rsvp).data('user-id')
        var rsvp_id = $(.rsvp_id).data('rsvp-id')

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "users/" + user_id + "/rsvps/" + rsvp_id
        }).done(function(response){ console.log('hello?', response)
        })
    })
})
```

App currently breaks down with `ActionController::UnknownFormat in RsvpsController#update` at the `respond_to` line. This posting is an extension of [this one, which is trying to solve too many problems at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183987/using-ajax-jquery-for-update-action-without-page-reload).

log

```
Processing by RsvpsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "rsvp"=>{"event_id"=>"16", "status"=>"attending"}, "user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"11"}
  Rsvp Load (3.3ms)  SELECT  "rsvps".* FROM "rsvps" WHERE "rsvps"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Event Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "rsvps" SET "status" = $1 WHERE "rsvps"."id" = $2  [["status", 2], ["id", 11]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 82ms (ActiveRecord: 20.6ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/rsvps_controller.rb:19:in `update'
```

**UPDATE**

in my routes file, I did `resources :rsvps, defaults: { format: 'js' }`. This got the app to process the request as JS, instead of HTML, but now it renders the update.js.erb file. DB gets updated, but no partial reload happens as desired.

Comment: Hi - so what shows up in your log/console when you submit the form? (it should show something even if the controller isn't correctly responding)

Comment: `Processing by RsvpsController#update as HTML
  Parameters:` then at SQL commit `Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 82ms (ActiveRecord: 20.6ms)`. It seems to be looking for an HTML template, is that a problem here?

Comment: What's the line right above the error that tells what params come through (including the format requested)? That might help us... if your AJAX is somehow still asking for html-format... then we at least have a place to start

Comment: Ok, so it's definitely not passing through the request as a JS request - which means there's something wrong with the calling-code, rather than the controller-code (which is correctly attempting to send back the html that was asked for... even though that's not what you were intending). the answer given below looks like it might be a good place to start.

Comment: small update at the bottom of OP

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "users/" + user_id + "/rsvps/" + rsvp_id,
        contentType: "text/javascript"

    }).done(function(response){ 
       console.log('hello?', response)
    })
```

Or

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "users/" + user_id + "/rsvps/" + rsvp_id.js
    }).done(function(response){ 
       console.log('hello?', response)
    })
```

Comment: where do I put the user_id and rsvp_id definitions instead?

Comment: @sivanes - add in the bits you need to make it work... I think the relevant line there is the `contentType` line - as long as you add that to your existing code, it could all Just Work :)

Comment: contentType did not change anything

Comment: hmm, actually now I wonder... can you edit your question to include the template that displays the link? It's plausible that whatever you're clicking on has a link which is getting activated before the AJAX gets a chance to be called? (totally guessing) - seeing what you actually have (and if possible also what that gets converted to as html on the page) would help us figure out if it's that kind of error.